# Installing Roboguice in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, roboguice

I would like to use Roboguice in an Android project using Android Studio and Gradle. I have been following [their installation guide](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/InstallationGradle) but I'm new to both Gradle and Android Studio, and I'm not sure how the pieces fit together.

Essentially, I've changed app's `build.gradle` file include something like;

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
  provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
}
```

After syncing the changes in Android Studio, I'm expecting to access `RoboActivity` and the like, but I can't find the references.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "can't find the reference".  Does this mean you are adding RoboActivity to a java file and the compiler can't find it?  Thanks.

Comment: That's spot on, I am supposed to extend my classes with `RoboActivity`, but the error I get is `Cannot find symbol class RoboActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to read up more about Gradle and how it works. Ultimately, I found quite a few references to `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()` repositories.

Both mavenCentral and jcenter are java-based package repositories (a bit like Nuget for .NET).

I'm guessing that Roboguice isn't available in jcenter, because if you use mavenCentral, everything appears to work. In order to change your repository, you change your project-level `gradle.build` file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
// to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad you found it.  Although do you mean "jcenter" not "jCentral".  That might explain why it wasn't found since jcenter gets most things from Maven Central automatically.  Also, were you able to find any error messages (maybe in the "Run" view) stating that the library could not be found.  Kind of a bother to have to guess that just from the java editor.

Comment: @AndroidGuy Thanks for the correction. If jcenter gets things from maven, then it should have found it, I'm guessing. I checked for messages and the like, but I couldn't find anything. Thanks for your help.